# Padding-right too large

Tags: html, css

My title box is too wide. It should only be as wide as the title-text inside it called "WEBSITE TITLE".

Is it possible to get my padding-right to be the same as my current padding-left which would be around 5px?

FIDDLE HERE... [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/rabas007/sunp5usj/)

HTML:

```
<footer class="main_footer">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <div class="text-center-footer-text">       
                        <a href="#">
                            <h4>WEBSITE<span> TITLE</span></h4>
                        </a>    
                    </div>
                    <p>Cool website.</p>
                    <p><a href="#">text1</a></p>
                    <p><a href="#">text2</a></p>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</footer>
```

CSS:

```
.text-center-footer-text h4 {
    font-size: 20px;
    padding: 5px;
    color: green;
    font-family: Agency FB;
    font-weight: normal;
    background-color: black;
    border: 5px solid blue;
}

.text-center-footer-text h4 span {
    color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `display: inline-block` or `display: table` to `h4`

```css
.text-center-footer-text h4 {
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 5px;
  color: green;
  font-family: Agency FB;
  font-weight: normal;
  background-color: black;
  border: 5px solid blue;
  display: inline-block;
}
.text-center-footer-text h4 span {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<footer class="main_footer">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <div class="text-center-footer-text">
            <a href="#">
              <h4>WEBSITE<span> TITLE</span></h4>
            </a>
          </div>
          <p>Cool website.</p>
          <p><a href="#">text1</a>
          </p>
          <p><a href="#">text2</a>
          </p>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</footer>
```

Comment: great, thanks. I accept your answer as solution once the system lets me.

Comment: Thanks :) Seems like `display: table` would be better since it retains the margin as in the question.

Answer (score 1):

try with

```
display:inline-block.
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sunp5usj/2/

hope this helps.

Regards!